# При запуске скомпилированного .asm файла выводятся непонятные значки

Tags: ассемблер

Есть .asm файл следующего содержания:

```assembler
.MODEL small
.STACK
.DATA
    PRMP db 'Input a:','$' 
.CODE
B10PRMP PROC NEAR   
    MOV AH,09
    LEA DX,PRMP 
    INT 21H
    RET 
B10PRMP ENDP
END
```

Все действия выполняю в DOSBox'е, сначала **tasm l3asm.asm**, затем **tlink l3asm,** после линковщика запускаю прогу командой **l3asm**

 Сам файл l3asm.asm лежит в папке BIN Борланда Си (BC\BIN) 
 
Результат выполнения следующий:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

 После данного вывода ничего больше ввести нельзя, фактически, DOSBox виснет. Так вот, откуда берутся эти непонятные значки и как исправить зависание?

Comment: А регистр DS у вас куда показывает?

Comment: @klopp, я в ассемблере не очень силен, этот код скопировал с методички, чтобы понять как и что работает. Если не сложно, подскажите, как проверить куда показывает регистр DS?

Comment: Значит, такую методичку - в помойку, без вариантов. Сейчас ответ сделаю.

Comment: @klopp если можно поделитесь хорошими материалами по теме на русском.

Comment: См. обновление ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Борланде есть нормальный (по крайней мере для TASM) отладчик. Запустите программу в нём и посмотрите, что содержится в регистре DS. Явно не адрес вашего сегмента данных. В `small` и `medium` моделях вы должны начинать программу так (если, конечно, сегмент данных в принципе используется - что обычно в таких моделях памяти и бывает):

```
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
```

И на будущее: многие вопросы отпадут, если вы научитесь пользоваться отладчиком и своими глазами будете смотреть что именно происходит в вашем коде.

---

Что касается материалов. Эти ассемблеры я забросил ещё в прошлом веке и даже не представляю где что читать, чем они могут быть интересны и вообще зачем на них убивать время. Единственный ассемблер, который до сих пор использую - [NASM](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/nasm/). Поддерживает он кучу платформ, так что вполне юзабелен. Ещё бывает [GAS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler). Но у меня - очень-очень редко, только когда сталкиваюсь с необходимостью что-то править в чужом и экзотическом коде.

Материалов по NASM в сети навалом, начиная с первой ссылки. Синтаксис его вполне понятен привыкшим к TASM/MASM, так что с этим проблем быть не должно. А все эти "модели памяти tiny/small/meduim/compact/large/huge" и прочие наследия DOS можно смело выкинуть как окаменелости, представляющие собой только узкий музейный интерес.

Впрочем, если вы программируете какие-нибудь однокристаллки... Но это уже совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: спасибо, ваш код помог избавиться от значков)) правда после вывода все равно все виснет и в досбоксе больше ничего нельзя ввести после выполнения проги, но да ладно. А насчет борланда и отладчика, я бы рад запустить программу там, но при компиляции выскакивает ошибка Linking L3.EXE: Undefined symbol _main in module c0.ASM, судя по всему при линковке он не может найти функцию main, но тут уж я не знаю куда лезть, чтобы это исправить:)

Comment: При чём тут main? Вы же собираете exe безо всяких main, вот и загрузите этот exe в TD. Для ясности можно включить отладку при сборке самим тасмом (ключ `/zi`). Вот в TD и увидите где виснет. (на самом деле у меня есть подозрения, что вы писали код по методичке для модели `tiny`, отсюда и некоторые э... особенности. но лучше своими глазами увидеть, что произойдёт после `ret` в вашем случае)